# Javascript not running in a fragment call

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf.

In a thymeleaf page I do

```
<html th:lang="${#locale.language}">
   <head th:include="fragments/head :: HeadCss"/>
   <body>
      <div th:replace="fragments/top-menu :: TopMenu('test')"></div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="main" class="main">
      <!--display info about how many for durability, granularity, scalling, flexion...-->
      <div role="tabpanel">
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <form>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="testType" th:text="#{testTypeEnum.select.label}"></label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="testType" >
                     <option th:value="NULL" selected="selected" th:text="#{form.select.empty}"></option>
                     <option th:each="testType : ${testTypes}" th:value="${testType}" th:text="#{'testTypeEnum.'+${testType}}"></option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
         <div id="testListResultFragment">
         </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#testType").on('change', function() {
            var valueSelected=  this.value;
            var url = "/samplestesttable?testTypeValue="+valueSelected;
            $("#testListResultFragment").load(url);
          });
        });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When user select something in the select, I do return via a ajax call a thymeleaf fragment.

Returned fragment look like

```
<div th:fragment="TestList" th:remove="tag">
  <table id="samplesTestsTable" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th th:text="#{id}">Sample</th>
        <th th:text="#{buildDate}">Build date</th>
        <th th:text="#{productTypes}">Product Types</th>
        <th th:text="#{products}">Products</th>
        <th th:text="#{suppliers}">Supplier</th>
        <th th:text="#{machines}">Machine</th>
        <th th:text="#{test}">Test</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>

  <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

      var samplesTestTable = $('#samplesTestsTable').DataTable({
         ....
         'fnDrawCallback': function (oSettings) {
           $('.dataTables_filter').each(function () {
             $("div.samples-toolbars").html('<div><input type="checkbox" id="testDoneInclude" name="testDoneInclude" class="form-check-input" /><label for="testDoneInclude" class="form-check-label">Test done include</label></div>');
             });
          },
      }); 

     $("#testDoneInclude").on('change', function(){
          //no called
     };

    });
  </script>

</div>
```

TestDoneInclude change event is never called

thanks

Answer (score 2):

jQuery binds to elements that exists in the DOM. You're binding to `#testDoneInclude` before it is generated. The easiest workaround is to delegate the binding to an ancestor element that you know will be on the page at the time the event binding is performed. So, for example,

```
 $('.dataTables_filter').on('change', "#testDoneInclude", function(){
      // Will be called when "#testDoneInclude" changes
 };
```

However, note an important observation.

The way `id` properties work in HTML is that the page expects exactly one element with a unique id name.

```
$('.dataTables_filter').each(function () {
   $("div.samples-toolbars").html('<div><input type="checkbox" id="testDoneInclude" name="testDoneInclude" class="form-check-input" /><label for="testDoneInclude" class="form-check-label">Test done include</label></div>');
    });
},
```

The `each` loop in the snipper above creates one checkbox for each each row in `'.dataTables_filter'`, and therefore you have several checkboxes all with the same unique id. This is where an attribute may be useful. I use custom attributes (think something that starts with `data-`, I like `data-hook`) and then bind to all of these generated elements. So if you create the following element:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="testDoneInclude" name="testDoneInclude" class="form-check-input" /><label for="testDoneInclude" class="form-check-label" 
  data-hook="test-done-include"> // This is our custom attribute
```

You'd bind it, similarly like above,

```
 $('.dataTables_filter').on('change', "[data-hook="test-done-include"]", function(){
      // Will be called when "#testDoneInclude" changes
 };
```

(note the brackets [data-hook="test-done-include"]`). And your DOM will be valid.

Of course you'll have issues if this is within a form, since forms require a `name` or `id` attribute. And your `label` will not work if it doesn't wrap the `input`. In cases like this, you may still want the `data-` attribute for event binding, but you'll have to use a generated id to play friendly with `form`s and `label`s.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! +1